# Postgresql installed on Mac OS X but no /usr/local/psql

Tags: macos, postgresql, installation

I have postgresql installed on Mac OS X, and can clearly see it's installed because I have it running on port 5432. However, it's not using /usr/local/postgres as it's root like it's supposed to.

How can I tell where it's installed? Also is there anything problematic about it not being installed in that location?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a query to show you the locations of the files that postgresql "knows" about internally:

```
SELECT current_setting('data_directory') data_directory, current_setting('config_file') config_file, current_setting('hba_file') hba_file, current_setting('ident_file') ident_file, current_setting('external_pid_file') external_pid_file;
```

You can check for the location of the postmaster process from the command line with:

```
ps aux | grep bin/postgres | head -n 1 | sed -e 's/.*[[:digit:]] //'
```

pg_config is usually located in the same directory, so you can find out the location of anything else from there.

Comment: Thanks that worked great, but again is there any downside to my configuration not being installed/located in /usr/local/postgres?

Comment: Not really.  You may want to put it in your PATH, but it will work fine from anywhere.